# Wierd behavior with onkeypress event Page reloads if "return false;" is missing else it wont let me key in any characters

Tags: javascript, ajax, jsp

Hi I've a strange problem with call to javascript function (which in turn has an AJAX call)on when pressed "Enter"

```
<html:text styleId="searchApp"  property="searchApp" style="margin-left:10px;width:100%;" onkeypress="javascript: if(event.keyCode == 13) callToJSFuncWhichHasAjaxCall(); return false;"/>
```

When I give the above statement I can't key in any characters apart from enter.

```
<html:text styleId="searchApp"  property="searchApp" style="margin-left:10px;width:100%;" onkeypress="javascript: if(event.keyCode == 13) callToJSFuncWhichHasAjaxCall();">
```

When I issue the above statement, and Press enter AJAX method is called and the whole page gets refreshed.

Please Help. TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Missing { and } is killing you there

Your code is basically

```
 if(event.keyCode == 13) { 
     callToJSFuncWhichHasAjaxCall(); 
 } 
 return false;
```

Every key press is being cancelled because every key press is calling the `return false`.

What you need it to include the return false with your check by surrounding it with brackets.

```
if(event.keyCode == 13) { callToJSFuncWhichHasAjaxCall(); return false; }
```

Comment: Oops Basic thing..!! Forgot..! I need to downvote my question.!

Comment: Thnx for a quick turn back @epascarello

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really understanding the whole problem, but there is nothing strange in not letting you any other characters beside enter. The "return false" statement prevents the input field from making other input.

The reloading of your document should be caused by "form" tags around your input field. Try to remove them, to prevent any reloading by hitting enter.

Answer (score 0):

Returning `false` from the `onkeypress` event will cancel the event, and is normal behaviour. Your condition is not doing what you want. The return false is a separate statement so you need to do:

```
javascript: if(event.keyCode == 13) { callToJSFuncWhichHasAjaxCall(); return false };
                                    ^ include these                                ^
```

A better approach might be to use the form's `onsubmit` event because an enter keypress wil trigger the event, which you can do the ajax then return false or preventDefault to prevent the form from submitting. This would be better than handling enter keypresses for all your inputs.

```
window.onload = function(){
    document.getElementById("myform").onsubmit = function(){
       callToJSFuncWhichHasAjaxCall();

        return false;
    };
};
```